# What's the meaning of the title of the song "Echame la cupla"?

Tags: meaning, song-title

What is the *meaning* of the title (not just the translation) in Luis Fonsi and Demi Lovato's song [*Echame la Culpa*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TyHvyGVs42U).

The lyrics can be found [here](https://genius.com/Luis-fonsi-and-demi-lovato-echame-la-culpa-lyrics).

Comment: What research have you done so far? The lyrics are easily googelable.

Comment: ... probably because we have a very high ratio of poor questions on this beta site, unfortunately - showing little effort, zero research; going so far as to not even bother to actually put a whole sentence into the question body, just a song title. Please take the time to read through the [Help pages](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/help) in order that the quality of questions on here may improve.

Comment: @SPnL We actually do want to help you, but it is not easy to understand what you are asking. There are not much details on your question, not even a link to hear the song or a link to the lyrics... you can edit your question if you want :-)

Comment: It could be translated "Put the blame on me", but I don't know how it actually relates with the song.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to *Genius*:

> “Échame La Culpa” (“Put The Blame On Me”) features Demi Lovato who puts her Spanish skills to the ultimate test in the track. The track describes the fact that both singers put the blame for the mistakes in love on themselves instead of the other person. Eventually, the song ends in a compromise to stay together.
>
> https://genius.com/Luis-fonsi-and-demi-lovato-echame-la-culpa-lyrics